# ViewPager is not working after adding ScrollView to layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, fragment

I added ViewPager () to the layout (root is RelativeLayout) 
Problem is if I try to keep the root into  so that I can slide the screen,but content of Viewpager is not visible, without adding Scrollview it is showing the content.

My Code activity_profile.xml

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_imageview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/header" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/informations_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_imageview"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="32dp"
            android:paddingTop="32dp"
            android:weightSum="1">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test Header"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Doctor Certificate"
                android:textColor="#FF707070" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="2nd line description"
                android:textColor="#FF909090" />

            <net.thrymr.mednetwork.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/informations_container"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-16dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/informations_container"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <net.thrymr.mednetwork.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs_profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:layout_weight="0.24"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

ProfileActivty.java

```
  mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
  mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);

    slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs_profile);
    //  mViewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), titles));
    slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    slidingTabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.accentColor);
        }
    });
```

Comment: whats is error on your Log cat

Comment: No errors... just its not displaying

Answer (score 0):

I tried this same thing some time back and had this exact same problem as I remember.

You need to add `android:fillViewport="true"` to the `ScrollView` element and everything will be perfect.

Comment: Yes I added but nothing get changed.... i think that the problem is with the fragments which are inflating to the pager. Aritra Roy

Comment: @AritraRoy  can u pls suggest any other option .... i m also getting same issue with design tablayout+viewpager inside of scrollview

Comment: can u pls suggest any other option .... i m also getting same issue with design tablayout+viewpager inside of scrollview @Mitesh Ukate

Comment: me too facing the same